# The list of problems for Grothendieck's thesis

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview

Is the list of open problems which were given by Dieudonne and Schwartz to Grothendieck for his thesis published somewhere? I know a quotation of Dieudonne that the problems concerned duality theory for general locally convex spaces.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [Chapter 3. From student to celebrity: 1949-1952](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Mathematics/chap3.pdf) on Grothendieck Circle it was the 14 questions found at the end Dieudonne and Schwartz's article *La dualite dans les espaces $\mathcal{F}$ et $\mathcal{LF}$* which can be found on [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/73677).